# how to add a line having special character by using shell script

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have to add a line having special character and this is my line .

```
sed -I  's/)/File have something 'example')/g' "example.ctl";
```

[image]

What I want output as  along with that single quote

```
File have something ‘example’
```

how to do this ?

Comment: Are you trying to turn those simple single quotes into fancy open/close single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

with double quotes

```
echo "hello (world)" | sed "s/)/ with an 'example')/"
```

give

```
hello (world with an 'example')
```

with complex quotes :

```
echo "hello (world)" | sed "s/)/ with an hello ‘example’ )/"
hello (world with an hello ‘example’ )
```